# How can I remove left padding on TimelineItem?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

using Timeline to list some informations, there are 3 columns `TimelinItem`, `TimelineSeparator`, and `TimelineContent`, I set `TimelineItem` padding 0 , it doesn't work , as code

`<Trace/>` is the sub-component of `<DialogContent>` in TraceDialog.js

trace.js

```
style={{margin:0,padding:0}}
```

```
    const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
      timeline: {
        padding: 0,
        margin: 0,
      },
      content: {
        padding: 0,
        margin: 0
      },
      secondaryTail: {
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
      },
    }));

export default function Trace (props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
    return (
              details.map((row) => (
              <Timeline key={row.stamp} align="alternate">
                <TimelineItem style={{margin:0,padding:0}}>
                  <TimelineOppositeContent>
                    <Typography variant="caption" color="textSecondary">
                      {TimeFormat(row.time)}
                    </Typography>
                  </TimelineOppositeContent>
                  <TimelineSeparator>
                      <TimelineDot color={row.first ? "primary":"grey"}/>
                      {!row.last ? <TimelineConnector /> : null}
                  </TimelineSeparator>
                  <TimelineContent>
                      <Typography variant="caption" className={classes.content} align="justify">{row.remark} </Typography>
                  </TimelineContent>
                </TimelineItem>
            </Timeline>))
          );
}
```

TraceDialog.js

```
    const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        margin: 'auto',
        minHeight: '400px',
        maxHeight: '600px',
    },
  }));

    export default function TraceDialog(props) {
      const classes = useStyles();

    
      return (
        <div>
          <Dialog
            className={classes.root}
            open={openTrace}
            onClose={handleClose}
            scroll='paper'
            fullWidth={true}
            aria-labelledby="scroll-dialog-title"
            aria-describedby="scroll-dialog-description"
          >
            <DialogTitle id="scroll-dialog-title">{'运单号:' + waybillno}</DialogTitle>
            <TraceStepper status={status}/>
            <DialogContent ref={descriptionElementRef} classes={{ MuiDialogContent: '2px,2px' }}>
                <Trace waybillno={waybillno} type={type} extra={extra}/>
            </DialogContent>
            <DialogActions>
              <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
                退出
              </Button>
            </DialogActions>
          </Dialog>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

[image: as the picture below]

Comment: What can you see as the styling when you look in your browser's dev tools inspect facility? It looks as though something is centering that rather than adding padding or margin.

Comment: Please post CSS which is applied here. This is only partial code. Cannot debug with this information.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=css+too+much+padding+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: The problem is probably here `<DialogContent ref={descriptionElementRef} classes={{ MuiDialogContent: '2px,2px' }}>` but I agree with the other commenters, that this is an incomplete question, without seeing what styles are being applied to these elements, for example from Chrome dev tools.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
<Timeline
         sx={{
          [`& .${timelineItemClasses.root}:before`]: {
              flex: 0,
               padding: 0,
                   },
                   }}> 

.....
</Timeline>
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove left padding You need to override your MUI styles inside **trace.js** `TimelineOppositeContent` like this

```js
   const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
         root: {
           flex: 0.2 
         }, 
         timeline: {
           padding: 0,
           margin: 0,
         },
         content: {
           padding: 0,
           margin: 0
         },
         secondaryTail: {
           backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
         },
       }));
   
   export default function Trace (props) {
     const classes = useStyles();
       return (
                 details.map((row) => (
                 <Timeline key={row.stamp} align="alternate">
                   <TimelineItem style={{margin:0,padding:0}}>
                     <TimelineOppositeContent className={classes.root}>
   ...
```